# JavaScript promise: order of evaluation

Tags: javascript, promise

I had a look at the [first example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Creating_a_Promise) of JavaScript promise on the promise page on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).  After I clicked 3 times fast on the `Make a promise!` button, I got the following result:

```
1) Started (Sync code started)
1) Promise started (Async code started)
1) Promise made (Sync code terminated)
2) Started (Sync code started)
2) Promise started (Async code started)
2) Promise made (Sync code terminated)
3) Started (Sync code started)
3) Promise started (Async code started)
3) Promise made (Sync code terminated)
2) Promise fulfilled (Async code terminated)
1) Promise fulfilled (Async code terminated)
3) Promise fulfilled (Async code terminated)
```

I totally understand that the lines `Promise fulfilled` can be inserted anywhere between the blocks of promise starting output (depending when the promise value actually becomes available), I don't understand why the `Promise started` lines are executed in sequence with `Started` and `Promise made` lines.

I would have expected an event to be place on the event queue, and the function passed to create a promise to be evaluated in its own context, after the `Promise made` instruction has completed.

It seems I missed something fundamental about promises, but I can't pinpoint what exactly.

Comment: Can you describe what you expected in more detail? For example, how would you expect that output to look instead of what happened?

Comment: The "executor" function that you pass to `new Promise()` is called immediately.  (That particular MDN page is absolutely terrible and doesn't explain that at all.)

Comment: Everything inside a promise function is called synchronously unless/until it is either (1) waiting for the result of another promise or (2) waiting for a callback to be called.

Comment: Thanks!  So if I understand correctly, it is only when a function "tagged as asynchronous or blocking" (in this case `sleep`) that the promise function is deferred.  But still, in case that example had not called `sleep`, the `then` function would execute asynchronously, right?

Comment: @FlorentGeorges: `Promise` constructor callbacks ("resolver") are always called synchronously, `then` method callbacks ("onFulfilled") are always called asynchronously.